# failed to initialize database, got error dial tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: connect: connection refused Problem

Tags: docker, go

im learning docker and go now
but i got the problem when i docker run with this
 `docker run --rm -p 8080:8080/tcp --env-file .env my-project:latest`
here are some of my .env code. i use docker desktop on windows, is it not possible to run docker on localhost in windows?

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_NAME=mydbs
DB_PASS=root123
AUTH_GEN_URL=https://api.learning.mydbs.id
```

anyone have a clue? any answer would be appreciated

thank youu

Comment: If you are getting connection refused on 127.0.0.1:3306, that means that there is no database service listening on that IP / port.  Yes it is possible to use localhost with Docker on Windows ... but you need to understand what it actually means.

Comment: But I reckon you should be asking this on Serverfault, because this is not a programming question.

Comment: ah i see, sorry i put the question in the wrong place, thank you for your reply !

Comment: oh and btw, there is the database the "mydbs" one, im still confused about this haha

Comment: In the default networking mode `127.0.0.1` refers to the container, not the Docker host. Every container gets its own network interface.

Comment: so i cannot connect to `127.0.0.1` with docker run code? i need to know the docker container host networking mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that when you spin up the container it tries to connect to `127.0.0.1:3306` within the container and not the host, hence you are getting the error as connection refused since nothing is running on port 3306 at localhost in your container.

For Windows and Mac this can easily be fixed by using `host.docker.internal` instead of `127.0.0.1`. This ensures that the service running inside your container correctly connects to the MySQL instance running on the host machine.

For Linux it's even more simple as all you have to do is pass `--network="host"` option to the `docker run` command

Comment: hello thank you for your reply, it works i thought you need to change it on mysql, but i try change it at my env file and it works, thankss

Comment: sorry for late reply, yesterday cant upvote it because my score still below 15, now i can, donee

Comment: Thanks for the reply I was struggling for days , couldn't figure it out why 127.0.0.1 was not connecting